# Regex split variable text into chunks of 90 or more characters

Tags: python, regex, text, split, python-re

I want to split some text of any length (1 - ∞) into chunks of 90 or more characters using **regex** in **python**.

The catch is that the text should only be split when there is a whitespace/line-break/new-line character after the 90-character limit has been reached. Also, if the last line of the text is less than 90 characters then it should get bunched with the second-last line.

Non-regex solutions are also welcome but only if they don't require/minimize character-by-character search for the whole text.

The closest I've come is `(?<=.{90})\s` but this only gets the first 90 characters properly, after that it starts breaking the entire text by every whitespace character it can find.

I do have a mixed solution but I'd like a pure regex one.

Edit: I know that the "combine last line if less than 90 characters" part can be achieved easily by editing the list itself after the regex, but then again if pure regex is possible, that would be much better.

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\S.{89,}?)(?:\s+|$)', text, re.S)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works pretty well, but it doesn't include the last line. I've updated the question for what happens to the last line "Also, if the last line of the text is less than 90 characters then it should get bunched with the second-last line."

Comment: Ok, use split, `re.split(r'(\S.{89,}?)(?:\s+|$)', text, re.S)`, but you might need to remove empty entries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Empty entries are not a problem, but this one is doing something weird. In some texts it's becoming "lazy" with the last line and leaves 1000+ characters, on the other it leaves less than 90 characters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are your reasons for regarding a pure regex solution to be "much better"?

Comment: *"if they don't require/minimize character-by-character search for the whole text."* Why? Regex doesn't work in O(1) either.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Speed is important here. I'm going by the assumption that since the regex engine has only one job, to work with strings, it would likely be optimized for that better than any high-level code. So unless the regex solution becomes too complicated, thereby reducing speed, I would prefer regex. If this is not the right approach, then do let me know.

Comment: @gre_gor Yes, but unless my last comment is incorrect, regex would be my go-to. Again, do let me know.

Comment: @raw_orb it is incorrect under many circumstances, simple text processing is usually quicker than initializing a regex parser. Not sure what's quicker here because you'd need to compare it to an optimized algorithm, but I'd bet on a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this should work (modified):

```
import re

def split_text(text):
    pattern = r'.{90,}?(?=\s|$)|.{1,89}(?=\s|$)'
    chunks = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    if len(chunks) > 1 and len(chunks[-1]) < 90:
        chunks[-2] += chunks[-1]
        chunks = chunks[:-1]
    return chunks
```

Comment: This leaves less than 90 characters in the last line. I want that last line, if it's <90 characters, to be added to the second last line.

Comment: I modified my code to work as you asked. Please try it out

Comment: That's great! But again it's not pure regex. I would prefer to use regex only first, and then this only if pure regex is not possible or way too convoluted.

Comment: I tried a few ideas but none seemed to do the trick with pure regex. I'll try again later

Answer (score 0):

```
\S              #                                             that starts with a non-whitespace
.{89,}?         # Match a string consists of 90 or more chars
(?:             # followed by
  (?=\s+|$)     # multiple whitespaces or end of line
|               # or
  .{1,89}(?!.)  # 1 to 89 chars then end of string,
)               # the latter of which is taken into the match.
```

Try it [on regexr101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KZ3y6H/1).

Comment: This doesn't work with e.g. the question's text https://regex101.com/r/QxFU77/1 It only works with texts of appriopriate length, else it may fail on matching at least 89 again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution, I tested it with a bunch of inputs and it worked, but there may be some sort of quirks I'm not thinking of or there may be something more optimal:

```
\S.{89,}?(?=\s|\Z)|.{1,89}\Z
```

Breakdown:

- `\S.{89,}?` matches a non-whitespace character followed by at least 89 other characters in a lazy way so that it doesn't match everything
- `(?=\s|\Z)` looks for any whitespace after that or the end of the whole input in case it ends with long string without whitespaces
- `.{1,89}\Z` is an alternative to match the remaining not long enough string until the end of the input

Of course it should use the "single line" flag to work. Example:
https://regex101.com/r/zveEZp/2

I'm not sure if you want to match the whitespaces that are missed, but that's easy to correct by changing the beginning to just `.{90,}`

But as I said in the comment to the question, I would recommend trying to build a non-regex loop solution instead.